# textinput text not submitting using onsubmitEditing using reactnative

Tags: react-native

here is my code the input not submit to the onsubmit function

```
<TextInput
          autoCapitalize={"none"}
          style={[styles.textInput, black, semi_h4]}
          returnKeyType="done"
          numberOfLines={1}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          onSubmitEditing={event => {
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            this.onSubmit();
          }}
          placeholder="Pin *"
          placeholderTextColor={"#313131"}
          ref={input => (this.c_pin = input)}
        />
```

please tell me how to working onsubmitediting

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass text from submit event to the function,

```
        <TextInput
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.onSubmit(event.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
```

Comment: have to get the value to function

Comment: Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `type` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around,     i got this error

Comment: Put it in a local variable and pass it `<TextInput
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => { let txt = event.nativeEvent.text; 
 this.onSubmit(txt)}}
        />`